# Spring Auto-Reconnect Database after Database Connection Loss

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

How do you auto-reconnect to Oracle when database connection is lost when using `BasicDataSource`? A possible scenario is a server being bounced every night a midnight.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: would using the validationQuery do the job?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3900476/2504224

Comment: Seems the answer is directed towards MySQL

Comment: Most of the properties that the are mentioned there are specific to BasicDataSource, not MySQL